# Viewing Text view

Tags: android, textview

I am having set of array string. and i want to display a string one by one on clicking the button. for example if i click the button at fist time it should display first string and again if i click the button it should display second string and so on.I dont know how to do this. can anyone guide me how to do this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ButtonDemo extends Activity{

Button btn1;
TextView tv;
static int cnt=0;
int len;
String[] mydata={"text1","text2","text3"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.btn);
    len=mydata.length;

    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView11);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(cnt==len)
            {
                cnt=0;
            }

            tv.setText(mydata[cnt]);
            cnt++;

        }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: Seeing that you are a new user on SO I'd like to teach you something about this site. It is not meant to be a code-request site where a developer faces a problem, asks for code and gets it right away. You should help him in a way that he can solve his problem himself, or at least try it. If he fails and asks why he failed, providing his non-working code, then you should try to highlight his mistake. In no way it is the desired approach to just dump in code as an answer. If you do then for the sake of the others please also explain what the code does.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean : Yaa. Ok. Remember this before posting new answer.

Answer (score 6):

Have your `OnClickListener` walk through your string array and set the next value in the array as the `TextView`s text on each click.

Comment: can  you give some sample for this..??

Comment: I'm sorry but no. I'm not here to write apps for someone else. Try it and if you fail show us what and how you've tried. I'll gladly help you then.

Comment: Thank you Mr octavian,Nice comments. I never said that i dint tried this issue so far. I failed to upload my code. I know you are not one to write codings for someone else. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Just copy the part of the code that does not work and paste it in your  answer, then mark that pasted code and hit the code-block button (the icon with the braces) next time and of course don't forget to explain what your pasted code block is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
int i=0;
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText(arrayItem[i]);
    i++;
            }
        });
```

this is how it works.